# Error updating oauth2client with pip install --upgrade

Tags: software-installation, pip

I am attempting to update oauth2client by using:

```
pip install --upgrade oauth2client
```

I get the following error message:

```
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement oauth2client in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Downloading/unpacking oauth2client
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for oauth2client in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log
```

pip.log says:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/pip run on Mon Aug 29 17:01:13 2016
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/oauth2client/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/oauth2client/: connectio$
Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/oauth2client/ when looking for$
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: connection error: ('Co$
Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download lin$
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
URLs to search for versions for oauth2client in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/di$
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/oauth2client/
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/oauth2client/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/oauth2client/: connectio$
Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/oauth2client/ when looking for$
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement oauth2client in /$
Downloading/unpacking oauth2client
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for oauth2client in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/$
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in $
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290$
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, $
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1177, in prepare$
    raise not_found
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for oauth2client in /us$
```

However, I do have oauth2client installed:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt-cache search oauth2client
python-oauth2client - OAuth 2.0 client library - Python 2.x
python3-oauth2client - OAuth 2.0 client library - Python 3.x
```

Please could someone advise as to why I am getting this error and how I can update oauth2client.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to install the package in my Raspberry pi 2 B+.

> pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/mytest $ sudo pip install --upgrade oauth2client
>   Requirement already up-to-date: oauth2client in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Requirement already up-to-date:

> httplib2>=0.9.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from
>   oauth2client)

Requirement already up-to-date:

> pyasn1>=0.1.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client)

Requirement already up-to-date:

> pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client)

Requirement already up-to-date:

> rsa>=3.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client)

Requirement already up-to-date:

> six>=1.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client)

Cleaning up... 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/mytest $

I think there is something blocking your network to get this package. I could see the message on your logs "Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/oauth2client/", However this link is available to get the package.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like there is a network problem.  Won't ping Google.  Will investigate a little further and most likely post another question!